# Load images from Flickr feed in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flickr, flash-cs5.5

I'm working in Adobe Flash CS5.5 (with ActionScript 3.0), and I'm trying to insert a Flickr feed. I want the Flickr images to show in a kind of gallery. This is my code so far, and the result of it is the Flickr feed in TEXT. How do I make it show the actual images?

```
import fl.controls.TextArea; 

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
var xmlData:XML = new XML(); 
var texten:TextArea = new TextArea(); 

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=snow&format=rss_200"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioErrorHandler);

function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(xmlData);
    texten.move(25,25);
    texten.setSize(500, 300); 
    addChild(texten);
    ParseXML(xmlData); 
}

function ParseXML(vaderInput:XML):void {
    var i:int = 0;  
    for each (var object:XML in vaderInput.channel.item) {
        texten.text += "" + object.title + "\r";
        texten.text += "" + object.description + "\r";
        texten.text += "\r";
        i++;
    } 
}

function ioErrorHandler(e:Event):void {
    trace('ERROR!');
    trace('Problems reading the XML-file!'); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have URLs in your feed? If yes, make an URLLoader to get each of these, and work with the results as images.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you show how the code would look?

Comment: You shuold load an image exactly as you load an XML, but instead of XML parsing you add your image to somewhere. The code is basically the same as your XML loader code.

Comment: I tried using URLLoaders, but can't make it work. I'm not used to working with actionscript, that's why I need help!

Answer (score 0):

Read the LiveDocs. You want to use a [`Loader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) to load the `<media:thumbnail/>` data in the XML. The Loader class extends DisplayObject, but includes much of the same properties/methods that `URLLoader` utilizes.

So, basically, you do something like this:

```
var l:Loader = new Loader();
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, loaderInitHandler ); //the majority of events for Loader are attached to its contentLoaderInfo property. That is the only reason I included this line
l.load( new URLRequest( /*url goes here*/ );
this.addChild( l );
```

That loads an image and *immediately* adds it to the stage. As soon as the image has loaded completely (Flash cannot display partially loaded images as far as I am aware), it will be viewable on the stage.

From there, you can treat the Loader, for the most part, as another Sprite/MovieClip.

Comment: In a blank project, throw the code above (and **only** that code) into the project and try loading https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png (the Google logo). `Loader` is *the* way to load images in AS3. It works. This is precisely what the class is meant for. Either the URL you are trying to load is bad, or you are messing something up along the way.

Comment: Actually, I still can't make it work - even if I'm **only** using that code. Don't know why.
But the Google logo is an **image**... The Flickr URL I'm using is an RSS feed. If I use this code, I can see an image:


`var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://natur.suntuubi.se/datafiles/gallery/1/lejon%20som%20ryter.jpg");
imageLoader.load(image);
addChild (imageLoader);
imageLoader.x = 200;
imageLoader.y = 300;`

But I can't use my RSS-URL that way. Also - the RSS contains lots of images, not one.

Comment: I just tried that exact code using http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8373/8560195640_fae1010eb5_b.jpg as the URL (taken directly from the RSS) and it works fine. Are you sure you are accessing the XML correctly? Accessing XML with namespaces requires a tad bit more work than standard XML. Trace out the URL you are trying to load and see what it is. My guess? It is either a blank string or null.

Comment: Yes, but that URL also ends with .jpg... My URL ends with rss_200. Have a feeling that's got something to do with it. As I said before, I can make jpg-URLs work just fine.

Comment: Instead of using RSS, which Flash has trouble with, why not use JSON? http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=snow&format=json The rss_200 just describes what format you want your data in. JSON is much, much easier to parse and use than XML with namespaces.

Comment: Thank you! I read somewhere before that you should use JSON in Flash, but I forgot. However, I don't know how to use the JSON-code in AS3 - when I try I get a security-error.